# A PowerShell Set-Member function and the usage of $_

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have been working on some PowerShell code and attempting to make it as readable as possible (something PowerShell is quite nice at). While we have an Add-Member function and a Get-Member function, there is no related Set-Member function. So I went about
creating one for my project. However, in the function itself (as shown below) it is requiring me to use the line:

```
$_.$NotePropertyName = $NotePropertyValue
```

to work. However, I think I should be using the line, but it doesn't work:

```
$InputObject.$NotePropertyName = $NotePropertyValue
```

Why is it reacting this way?

```
Function Set-Member
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Message')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Position=0,  ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [object[]]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Mandatory=$true)] [string]$NotePropertyName,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Mandatory=$true)] [string]$NotePropertyValue
    )
    $strInitialValue = $InputObject.($NotePropertyName)  # Get the value of the property FirstName
                                                         # for the current object in the pipe
    $_.$NotePropertyName = $NotePropertyValue
}


$objTest = [PSCustomObject]@ {
    FirstName = "Bob"
    LastName = "White"
}

$objTest | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-Member -NotePropertyName "FirstName" -NotePropertyValue "Joe"
    $_      # Push the object back out the pipe
}

$objTest | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-Member -NotePropertyName "FirstName" -NotePropertyValue "Bobby$($_.FirstName)"
    $_      # Push the object back out the pipe
}
```

Comment: I'm Sorry. but I really don't understand what's the purpose of this function

Comment: Hey CB....It really is just so those reading my code in-house see the verbiage "Set-Member" to make it very clear what it is doing.  My current code just does the change in line and makes sense to me, but I thought for future-proofing it would be nice to have a named cmdlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the $InputObject parameter as an array of objects. You should have a `for` loop in your function to iterate over the array and not treat it as a single object. Or change the type to `[object]` instead of `[object[]]`.

Since you use a pipeline to call the function you should use the [process block of the function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx) or you will only see the last item in the pipeline processed.

```
Function Set-Member
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Message')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Position=0,  ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [object[]]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Mandatory=$true)] [string]$NotePropertyName,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Message', Mandatory=$true)] [string]$NotePropertyValue
    )
    process
    {
        foreach ($obj in $InputObject)
        {
            $strInitialValue = $obj.($NotePropertyName)  # Get the value of the property FirstName
                                                         # for the current object in the pipe
            $obj.$NotePropertyName = $NotePropertyValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lars, Thank you so VERY much. That fixed it.  I really was only aiming for a single object, so I took your code and removed the [] and took out the foreach loop.  I also thank you for the note on the Process Block as I wasn't aware of that caveat.  All the best!